# Is it possible to rewrite the following component without the need for passing a function as a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to make a resuable button component that wraps some code related to loading and error when executing a function passed from its parent. Ive come up with the following approach to do this, but im passing a function as a prop which is an anti-pattern in vue.

AppExecButton - reusable button

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import type { ButtonVariant } from "@/components/types";

const props = defineProps<{
  onClick: () => Promise<unknown> | unknown;
  errorMessage?: string;
  variant?: ButtonVariant;
  disabled?: boolean;
  block?: boolean;
  color?: string;
}>();

const loading = ref(false);

async function handleClick() {
  loading.value = true;
  try {
    await props.onClick();
  } catch (e) {
    const errorMessage = props.errorMessage;
    if (errorMessage) {
      console.error(e);
      throw new Error(errorMessage);
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  } finally {
    loading.value = false;
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-btn
    @click="handleClick"
    :loading="loading"
    :variant="variant"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :block="block"
    :color="color"
  >
    <slot />
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

Some where in a parent component

```
<app-exec-btn
  :on-click="() => downloadNotes()"
  error-message="Failed to download notes"
  block
  variant="outlined"
>
{{ Download Notes }}
</app-exec-btn>
```

Is it possible to do this using events without having to write the try catch and loading state everytime in the parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a function is not an antipattern in general, it's so only when it can be replaced with more idiomatic event listener.

In this case it's not just a listener that have their return value being ignored but a callback that can return a promise:

```
await props.onClick();
```

It makes sense to call it differently than `onClick` to not interfere with Vue convention for event listeners, but otherwise it's totally legitimate here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your issue, so I apologise if I did, but couldn't you refactor this with emits?

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits(['clickOnParent']);

function clickOnChild() {
  // do your things on the child...
  emit('clickOnParent')
}

</script>

<template>
  <button @click="clickOnChild">Click Me </button>
</template>
```

And then on the parent you handle the emit @clickOnParent as you would normally do.
You would need to add the logic of "loading" in the parent handler and pass it as a prop, refactor some code to keep the async functionality, but other than that I think it should work?